# OpenFeint Integration with cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

[image: when ever]

when ever I drag and drop the openfeint in my project , and compile it, it give me the error that llvm-g++4.2 failed with exit code 1 , how can I solve it....????

however I add the all the frameworks but not find the solution yet???

Comment: I want both GameCenter and also Openfeint in my game

Comment: Are you adding the framework or the sources? From the "Duplicate symbol" error I suspect you added both. You can only use one or the other but not both. Either remove the framework or the sources folder from your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your openfeint framework.. and it solve your problem